# Xcode Lexical or Preprocessor issues in Xcode 11

Tags: c++, xcode, header, xcode11

The error is highlighted in the picture below. It only started after updating to Xcode 11. I tried fixing it by installing the Xcode command line tools but no idea what else I can do. The code still seems to run. How do I suppress these errors?

[image: Errors]

Comment: What's your minimum system version set to and what C++ libraries are you using (`stdlibc++` or `libc++`)?  I suspect you are have left the latter to the default (so it's now `libc++`) but your minimum system version is lagging behind.

Comment: 10.15 is the MacOS deployment target and I am using `libc++`

Comment: Also experiencing this issue after upgrading to Xcode 11.1

Comment: @daHolby even with the beta versions. I am not sure what to do and I am beginning to tear my tear.